# Searching first specified element in array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, loops, optimization

I'm trying to make function that has a loop that checks every member of an array made from boolean variables and exits when it finds the first "true" value.

That's what I have now:

```
    bool solids[50];
    int a,i;

//"equality" is a function that checks the equality between "a" and a defined value
solids[0] = equality(a,&value_1); 
solids[1] = equality(a,&value_1);
solids[2] = equality(a,&value_1);
solids[3] = equality(a,&value_1);

for (i = 0; solids[i] != true; i++)
{

[...]

}
```

But I have no idea, what should I put into the loop?

My attempt was

```
for (i = 0; i <= 50; i++)
{
    if (solids[i] == true)
    {
    return true;
    break;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
}
```

,that should return `true` after the first found true and return `false` if the array has no member with `true` value, but it doesn't seem to work in the code.

Is it wrong? If yes, what is the problem?

PS.: I may count the number of `true`s with a counter but that's not an optimal solve to the problem, since I just look for the FIRST `true` value and consequently, the program doesn't have to check all the 50 members. Needley to count, how many unnecesary steps should this solve would mean.

Comment: Just use `std::find`.

Comment: You don't need the `else` part. Think about it - it returns `false` for the first non-true value so it ceases searching.

Comment: Do you intend to set every member of solids[] to the same value? You are always comparing `a` to `value_1`

Comment: `break` after `return` is non sense, as it will never be reached by the compiler. And good algorithmic practices advices not to use loop control statements (like `break` or `continue`) in a traditional `for(;;)` loop, but only in while loops. A `for(;;)` is meant to begin at the start value and end when the ending condition is reached, to help keep code readable. Just FYI, anyway... And of course, don't reinvent the wheel, use `std::find`.

Comment: In the first example, what if *none* of the entries are `true`? Then you will continue to loop, maybe forever. In the second example you loop exactly once to many (use `i < 50` instead).

Comment: @zmo The practice you mention sounds silly. If you put the loop in a short enough function it's obvious enough that it exits prematurely.

Comment: after rereading, may I amend my last comment (without editing it, as I mean what I said): your first loop shall be a `while()` statement, even though it uses an index.

Comment: @zmo, I don't see the point. For loops are nearly conceptually equivalent to while loops, and I don't see why they should only differ by flow control methods.

Comment: Sorry guys, I didn't know about the existance of `std::find`.

Comment: Also, it's not for you, guys, but I'd be really happy if I'd know, what the heck was so bad in this question that I got 5 downvotes immediately...

Comment: @chris and @millimouse, well my point is only about methodology and readability. A traditional `for(i=N;i<M;++i){}` loop shall iterate over the whole range and not skip values or break in the middle, to help the reader not get unexpected things. And as you said, it is logically equivalent to a `while(){}` loop, where it is more expectable to see it break or skip. You could also tell me that `while` and `for` is logically equivalent to a `goto`, for which you were right, but (almost) nobody uses the `goto` statement, because it makes unreadable code!

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt I'd say mostly because http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a short example usage of [std::find()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) as advised by @chris:

```
bool find_element_in_array() {
    bool solids[50];
    int length;

    /* ... do many operations, and keep length as the size of values inserted in solids */

    bool* location = std::find(solids, length, true);
    // if element is found return true
    if (location != solids + length)
        return true;
    // else return false
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't you forget to form the first line?

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt: This won't compile. The second parameter to `std::find` should be an iterator (like the first parameter). The statement is also missing an `=`. I have no idea where `ARRAY_SIZE` came from (should be `length`).

Comment: sorry about the few mistakes I made, but outside of my vim I'm often doing typos :-) Otherwise, I mostly followed the documentation and example from the link I gave, and I consider it being a starting point for @ZoltánSchmidt for him to adapt to his needs.

Comment: That's why I marked this answer as the best, since even though I could find the description of `std::find`, it's a bit new for me but you tried to explain it at least. =)

Comment: If you are going to post code as an answer you could at least try to post correct code. Note: your `std::find` still won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have solids correctly set (it looks like you're currently setting every value to the same thing), you can make a loop that exits on the first true like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    if (solids[i] == true)
    {
        return true;
    } 
}
return false;
```

I'd also just move the declaration of `i` into the `for` loop body, since it's not used outside, but the above answers your question.

Comment: `i<=50` is an incorrect condition for an array of 50 items. Should be `i<50`.

Comment: True, I copied that loop and didn't inspect it

Answer (score 0):

`return` immediately exits the function, so there is no need to `break` the loop after.

If it's sufficient to exit the function right after the search, you should write something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  if (solids[i]) return true;
}
return false;
```

If you need to use the result of the search in the same function, use additional variable:

```
bool found = false;
for (int = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  if (solids[i]) {
    bool = true;
    break;
  }
}

if (found) { ...
```